# Check if element is in documents of rdd

Tags: mapreduce, apache-spark, pyspark

I have such rdd1 in pySpark: (please excuse any minor syntax errors):

```
[(id1,(1,2,3)), (id2,(3,4,5))]
```

I have another rdd2 holding such: (2,3,4).

Now I want to see for each element of rdd2 in how many rdd1 sublists it occurs, e.g. of expected output rdd (or collected list I dont care)

```
(2, [id1]),(3,[id1,id2]),(4,[id2])
```

This is what I have so far (note that rdd2 must be the first item in the line/algorithm)

```
rdd2.map(lambda x: (x, x in rdd.map(lambda y:y[1])))
```

Even though thus would me give only true/false as second item of the pair tuple I could live with it, but even thus does not work. Failing when trying to perform a map on rdd2 inside the anonymous function of the rdd1 map.

Any idea how to get this going in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

If `rrd2` is relatively small (fits in memory):

```
pairs1 = rdd1.flatMap(lambda (k, vals): ((v, k) for v in vals))
vals_set = sc.broadcast(set(rdd2.collect()))
(pairs1
    .filter(lambda (k, v): k in vals_set.value)
    .groupByKey())
```

If not, you can take `pairs1` from a previous part and use join:

```
pairs2 = rdd2.map(lambda x: (x, None))
(pairs2
    .leftOuterJoin(pairs1)
    .map(lambda (k, (_, v)): (k, v))
    .groupByKey())
```

As always, if this only an intermediate structure you should consider `reduceByKey`, `aggregateByKey` or `combineByKey` instead of `groupByKey`. If it is a final structure you can add `.mapValues(list)`.

Finally you can try to use Spark Data Frames:

```
df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
    rdd1.flatMap(lambda (v, keys): ({'k': k, 'v': v} for k in keys)))
df2 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd2.map(lambda k: {'k': k}))

(df1
    .join(df2, df1.k ==  df2.k, 'leftsemi')
    .map(lambda r: (r.k, r.v)).groupByKey())
```